# Can I use mapWithState() like updateStateByKey() in Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, stateful

I'm using the function mapWithState() instead of updateStateByKey() to load initial state and use timeout. But I need to update the entire state store, regardless of whether a new value for a given key has been consumed or not.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this. As described [here](https://blog.yuvalitzchakov.com/exploring-stateful-streaming-with-apache-spark/), you will not/can not update an entire state store due to the nature of `mapWithState`.